# More personalized close message for uninformed people

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

When a question is closed, the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions is presented. For completely uninformed beginners who have not even read the introductory tour, it would be more helpful to start with reminding them that they have not read the tour. Currently I [do this manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667096/detecting-human-from-machine-in-prolog), it would be helpful if this could be done automatically.

Related: [Demand that page about a privilege is read to get privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163739/demand-that-page-about-a-privilege-is-read-to-get-privilege)

Comment: You shouldn't assume that they did not read the introductory tour just because they posted a bad question, it could be that they don't care and just want an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure they're any more likely to read it and pay attention the second (or third, or hundredth) time than they were the first. People who are wilfully ignorant of the way the community is intended to work will probably continue to be so. I like your related feature-request though -- shame that was declined.

Comment: @JoeW: If they did not receive the "Informed" badge, they did not read it (at least as that very person).

Comment: I have read through it before and not gotten the informed badge because it can seem picky about everything you need to do to get it.

Answer (score 8):

Aside from the one very short block about "Get answers to practical, detailed questions"

[image]

there's nothing in the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that talks about question quality.

That block doesn't even come close to the information that's offered in the ["How to ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which is presented as a click-through that new askers must acknowledge that they have read. Of course they can skip it and check the box regardless, but if that's the case, I don't see how pointing them to the tour when they've already ignored a better source is going to be helpful.

Point them back at "How to ask", if anything.